# Why Is assertThat Not Functioning Correctly When Checking For String Equality?

Tags: java, string, junit

So a fairly simple one and I have resolved it by using assertEquals instead but just curious to know why this didn't work:

```
assertThat(list.get(0).getStringValue().equals("1234567811"));
```

The above line, after checking the variables during debugging, would count as a pass even when the String retrieved did not match.

When I use:

```
 assertEquals(list.get(0).getStringValue(), "1234567811");
```

It correctly picks up errors.

It was my understanding that assertThat should work for this too so I am curious as to why it doesn't?

Thanks

Comment: Which package are you getting assertThat from? As far as I can tell it takes 2 arguments, a value and a matcher.

Comment: In addition to @mwarren's comment, `assertEquals` also takes 2 arguments, since you want to check if A is equal to B. In the latter case, it should be `assertTrue(...)`

Comment: yes  you are correct I have corrected how I actually wrote the assertEquals bit. The import I'm using is : org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat

Comment: seems like could just be the way assertJ functions: https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-converting-junit-assertions-to-assertj.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to have this form for it to work properly

```
assertThat(actual, is(equalTo(expected)));
```

so it should be something like this

```
assertThat(list.get(0).getStringValue(), is("1234567811"));
```

or

```
assertThat(list.get(0).getStringValue(), equalTo("1234567811"));
```

can read more here

https://objectpartners.com/2013/09/18/the-benefits-of-using-assertthat-over-other-assert-methods-in-unit-tests/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like AssertJ uses a fluent approach so you would need to do something like

```
assertThat(list.get(0).getStringValue()).isEqualTo("1234567811");
```